Are there any poskim who rule that one can place the Aron Kodesh on the western facing wall if it is more convenient?
The Mishnah Berurah (94, 9) rules that one should pray facing east and therefore place the Aron Kodesh on the Eastern wall. However, he adds, that if that is impossible, one should place the Aron Kodesh on the Northern side. He then adds, "as long as it is not on the western side". Is this ruling unanimous or are there other poskim who allow it.

I know of at least one place that got a psak they can do that and they should just daven shemona esrei on an angle so their backs are not east. Can’t tell you who gave the psak though.

The answer depends on the country the synagogue is built. Mishna Berurah was written in Lithuania/Belarus. They should have faced south, not east. If Lithuanian Jews built a synagogue in South Africa, it should have faced north, not south like in Lithuania. The Christian churches face east. Perhaps the decree of the state and censorship caused such a statement in MB. Please correct that east is in US, Western Europe.

related https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/18686/759

It’s worth noting that the placement of the Aron Kodesh in the synagogue is to be on the side facing the Temple in Jerusalem. To place the Aron Kodesh on the western wall is following the ruling of the Muslims, who according to their prophet, specifically turn their back away from the Temple in Jerusalem nullifying the prophecy of Moshe and face Mecca. The prohibition is much more than simply a direction other than toward the Temple in Jerusalem.

Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1043/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/7307/. The MB provides the reasoning in 94:5 that the backs of the people should not face the Aron Kodesh. See also Sukka 5:4 (see also Y'chezkeil 8:16 and Sukka 53b), "הגיעו לשער היוצא ממזרח הפכו פניהן למערב ואמרו אבותינו שהיו במקום הזה אחוריהם אל היכל ה' ופניהם קדמה והמה משתחוים קדמה לשמש ואנו לי-ה עינינו". See also Tosefta Megilla 3:14 based on B'midbar 3:38 ("והחונים לפני המשכן קדמה לפני אהל מועד מזרחה").
